# Can't find the compile errors

Tags: excel, vba

I've checked several times, no I haven't found any such debug errors, what should I do to get the code to bounce the messenger box?

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Expiry As Date
    Expiry "21 Oct 2022"
    If Date > Expiry Then .MsgBox "This File Has Expired. Please Download the latest version!", vbCritical, "File will close"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Quit
    Else
        MsgBox "You Have " & Expiry - Date & "Day(s) Left", vbInformation, "file Expires on " & Expiry
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Expiry "21 Oct 2022"` is no valid syntax. Also you try to push a string (text) `"21 Oct 2022"` into a numeric variable `Expiry As Date`. That does not work, `"21 Oct 2022"` is no date this is just a text. Use `Expiry = DateSerial(2022, 10, 21)` instead to create a numeric date. Also `.MsgBox` makes no sense and should be `MsgBox` aso it should start in a new line and not right behind `Then`.

Comment: Click on Debug -> Compile, and you'll see what the problem is. To be precise you have 3 syntax errors: `Expiry  "...""`  needs to be `Expiry = "..."`, `.MsgBox` needs to be `MsgBox` and `MsgBox` needs to be in new line. BTW, `Expiry = "21 Oct 2022"` actually works hm

Comment: Note that syntax errors are compiler errors, not runtime errors. You can catch them with the Command Debug->Compile and correct them *before* you execute the code.

Comment: Can I use "Cells.Clear" with "if" to add?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you have some compile errors you need to fix. Run <kbd>Debug</kbd> › <kbd>Compile</kbd> from the menu to fix them before running the code.

1. `Expiry "21 Oct 2022"` is no valid syntax (missing `=` sign). Also you try to push a `String` (text) `"21 Oct 2022"` into a numeric variable `Expiry As Date`. That does not work, `"21 Oct 2022"` is no date this is just a text.
   Use `Expiry = DateSerial(2022, 10, 21)` instead to create a numeric date.
2. `.MsgBox` makes no sense and should be `MsgBox` aso it should start in a new line and not right behind `Then`
3. `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus (is on top). This might change easily by a mouse click! Always use `ThisWorkbook` which is the workbook the code is running in, unless you really need to use the active workbook.
4. `Application.Quit` will kill all other opened workbooks too! Means if the user has a workbook opened and then opens your workbook and it is expired it will will the entire Excel. They will hate you for that. Check if you are the only workbook in that instance `Application.Workbooks.Count` and only then quit Excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Expiry As Date
    Expiry = DateSerial(2022, 10, 21)

    If Date > Expiry Then 
        MsgBox "This file has Expired. Please download the latest version!", vbCritical, "File will close"
        Dim QuitExcel As Boolean  ' check if we are the only workook
        QuitExcel = cBool(Application.Workbooks.Count = 1)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        If QuitExcel Then  ' only quit if we were the only workbook before closing it
            Application.Quit
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "You Have " & Expiry - Date & " day(s) left", vbInformation, "file expires on " & cStr(Expiry) ' or Format$(Expiry, "YYYY-MM-DD") to choose your date format. cStr(Expiry) will use the format of the operating system
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I use "Cells.Clear" with "if" to add?

Comment: @mirsspoomkissStpes I don't understand what this question has to do with your original question or with my answer. You need to be much more specific than just one sentence.

Comment: Incredible advice about Debug -> Compile Project. I actually didn't know that existed. I learned something very valuable today.